# Rails Routes for Versioned Web Services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm new to Rails. Can anyone tell me if the following is possible, and if you, what would the correct "route" entry be?

I have a controller ItemController with one action (index). When I set it up by default, it's accessible at http://my.app:3000/item, but I want this controller (i.e. this controller only, not the other controllers) to be accessible via http://my.app:3000/api/v1/.

Thanks x

Vanessa

Answer (score 1):

Set it up under a namespace:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :items
  end
end
```

Then you would need to move this controller into `app/controllers/api/v1/items_controller.rb` and call the class defined in it `Api::V1::ItemsController`.

Chances are that you're going to h ave some custom logic you want for API actions, so you may want to put that logic in another controller *other* than `ApplicationController`. This means this new controller would inherit from `Api::V1::BaseController` rather than `ApplicationController`.

On a side note, I cover this kind of thing in the "Designing an API" chapter of my book, [Rails 3 in Action](http://manning.com/katz).